# Some styles are not taken into account in minimized CSS

Tags: html, css, minify

I have 2 CSS files, select2.css and select2.min.css

When debugging, select2.css file is used, while select2.min.css is used in production.

I realized that the HTML controls that is affected by select2 styles looks ugly when using minimized version.

when comparing, I have found some differences... for example, when using select2.css, this style is applied:

```
.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
    border: solid black 1px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

However, when using minimized version, that style is not applied.

I opened select2.min.css and I have seen that style is there, this way:

```
.select2-container--default[dir=rtl] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{margin-left:2px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple{border:1px solid #000;outline:0}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:#eee;cursor:default}
```

I shown you the styles before and after the mentioned style for you to know if neighbor style could be affecting.

What may be happening here?

The corresponding HTML tag is this:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
```

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Are you using some automatic tool for the minification? If so have you tried to minifiy the css with some other tool online and see if something change?

Comment: @fcalderan I used this: https://cssminifier.com/.... however, independently on the tool used, the minified file is loaded by the browser.... the question is how it is not considered by it.